# Asp date format

Tags: iis, asp-classic

Asp Now()  function returns date in M/d/yyyy format in one server and d/M/yyyy in another server. I tried to set the Region format in 2nd server,  that changed the server time to the M/d/yyyy format, but Asp Now() function still return date in d/M/yyyy. I restarted the server and iis.

Is there any change required on iis to force asp Now()  function  return date in M/d/yyyy?

Comment: No, it goes off the System Locale. So it depends how you change the regionally settings, it needs to be the default region setting for the server not just the logged in profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try setting your Locales LCID value to get the format you want:

```
Session.LCID = xxx
```

where xxx is some value from https://www.pdshop.com/locale-id-lcid-code-list-currency-date-kb-21/